# MongoDB get index of current element in array

Tags: mongodb

For exmple i have an document witch contains following array:

```
...
posts: [
   {
      "content": "this is a post",
      "timestamp": 1242345,
   },
   {
      "content": "this is a second post",
      "timestamp": 1243345,
   }
]
....
```

How do i write the `find` query to get this result:

```
...
posts: [
   {
      "content": "this is a post",
      "timestamp": 1242345,
      "index": 0
   },
   {
      "content": "this is a second post",
      "timestamp": 1242345,
      "index": 1
   }
]
....
```

My idea was to add a new field with `$addFields` and then to get the index of the current element with  `$indexOfArray` but i dont know exactly how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with the following aggregation pipeline:

```java
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $set: {
            posts: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$posts",
                    in: {
                        content: "$$this.content",
                        timestamp: "$$this.timestamp",
                        index: { $indexOfArray: ["$posts", "$$this"] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```